# path variable changes in sql

Tags: sql-server, environment-variables, redgate

I'm not sure why but it looks like sql server is using a different path environmental variable then the rest of my system. When i add the cmd as an external tool in sql, by going to 
Tools->external Tools and adding cmd.exe as the command i get a different path.

the shell from sql gives me

```
echo %PATH%
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\;C:\Windows\system32\NV;.;
```

This does not reflect my path variable at all

when I echo the path from a regular command prompt I get my full path.

When SQL starts up it looks like it is using its own environmental variables. Does anyone know where these are defined or if I can have my system path appended to this "special" SQL path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but there is a sql subsystem to run commands, generally frowned upon as a security risk.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190264(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I need redgate to access my source control bin(ie git,perforce,svn) which is on the path. But when redgate runs it says that it the command is unrecognized. After digging in a little i found that sql is seeing a different system path than what I have set in the path environmental variable. But i cant find where this "special" path is coming from

Comment: Have you tried redgate support?  If you're paying for it, you should take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's very rare problem. I found only this topic and it without solution.
I faced same problem.

Stopping all services that on the screenshot (in running state) and start them again one by one solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL Source Control issue may be related to something else. You may want to check your path and make sure that it doesn't have extra backslashes or double-quotes in it -- DOS is fine with that but the dox for ProcessStartInfo in .NET say this will not be a recognized path. For instance
c:\windows;c:\git;"c:\program files\git\bin"

With Git.exe in any of the latter two path components, you could launch Git.exe from the command prompt but the command would fail in SQL Source Control.

Comment: what is wrong with c:\git? or is it the fact that double quotes exist in the path

Comment: I found some other bug on GIT forums that said you couldn't have double-quotes.